# Trying to find a movie about a boy who finds a buried spaceship that then takes off

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

I'm looking for a movie that I saw some 20 or so years ago.

There's a boy who wanders about the countryside and falls into a hole to find himself in a corridor. He looks around, explores things...not sure if anything special happens in the mean time. The boy was youngish...around 10, maybe younger. From what I remember, it was generally very dark, the corridor might have been covered with dry bush branches. There might have been old screens / machines / computers overgrown with vegetation, but I remember things to be dark, brown, black, ...rather than green.

The corridor is actually a part of a spaceship that's burried there and seems to be dead. Anyway towards the end the boy triggers something that makes the spaceship come alive and start to take off. Not sure if the boy gets out or stays.

I'm not sure, but the ship may have started to talk to the boy...by voice or text on a screen...but I feel like I might be making that up :-)

Now that I think of it that's how it might have been. The boy visiting regularly, somehow communicating with the thing. In the end the ship then decided to take off. Until that moment I think it wasn't really obvious that it was a ship at all. Just an old dusty underground "house".

That's as much as I remember.

Comment: Stephen King's Tommyknockers - part 2 - *Jim and Bobbi are two writers who one day literally stumbles over a buried spaceship in the woods. While they start to excavate the spot to uncover their finding the people in the nearby town is affected by the spaceship in different ways.* ?

Comment: How old was the boy? Was he white? Can you describe the corridor? Was this a children's film or something more like a scifi or a horror? When the ship tried to take off what happened? Big budget or low-budget?

Comment: Sounds a bit like Disney's [*Flight of the Navigator.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_of_the_Navigator)

Comment: I'm afraid it's not The Tommyknockers. Didn't know that one so I had my hopes up, but nope...

Comment: The boy was youngish, white...around 10 give or take a few years. From what I remember, it was generally rather dark, the corridor might have been covered with dry bush branches. There might have been old screens / machines / computers overgrown with vegetation, but I remember things to be dark, brown, black, ...rather than green...but as I said - it's quite long ago so the details are a bit fuzzy. The boy was visiting the site regularly.

Comment: I stumbled upon Flight of the Navigator before when searching for this and that's not it either. It wasn't a children's movie like that or like Explorers. 
I wouldn't say it was a horror movie either.

Comment: He might have found some dead gadgets and fumbled around with some of the ship's controls...

Comment: I'm not sure, but the ship may have started to talk to the boy...by voice or text on a screen...but I feel like I might be making that up :-)

Comment: Now that I think of it that's how it might have been. The boy visiting regularly, somehow communicating with the thing. In the end the ship then decided to take off. Until that moment I think it wasn't really obvious that it was a ship at all. Just an old dusty underground "house".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could it be the West German/Polish TV production from 1988 titled „Flugfieber“ („Flying Fever“) in German, and „Stworzony do lotu“ („Meant for flying“) in Polish?

In Germany, its first broadcast took place in 1988 on WDR channel, and it seems to have been repeated a couple of times in the 1990s. I didn‘t find out if it has been broadcasted anywhere outside Poland or Germany.

Here the imdb-site: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt12741734/

And here are the last 20 minutes of the film in German on Youtube:

It seems as if the only way to watch the whole film now is to request a copy from the respective television channel. The German version can be requested here:
https://wdr-mediagroup.com/geschaeftsfelder/i-o/mitschnittservice/

I found all this when I stumbled upon an old thread on a German speaking scifi-forum:

https://www.scifi-forum.de/forum/filme-tv-serien-und-co/tv-serien/36989-alte-scifi-serie-oder-film-gesucht

Comment: Wow this looks very promissing! It was a long long time ago so I am not sure, but since I am from Czech Republic and this had to run on one of our local TV stations I think this might actually be the movie!

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like Invaders From Mars (1953). It was [remade in 1986](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091276/).

Comment: Do you have a plot summary or some stills?

Comment: This looks familiar. I think I've seen it and I think it's not the one I mean. There's too much going on, too many people running around. The one I mean was more quiet. Plus it's a family movie.

Comment: There were no aliens in the movie. Just the boy and the buried ship. There might have been other characters, but not like this.

Comment: I don't have any stills. I just remember seeing this many years ago.

Answer (score 4):

Aquila, a Greek/Aztec-style space ship:
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0201376/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1

The Tomorrow People - there are various versions of this:
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103568/?ref_=fn_al_tt_3

Dark Season - Not a space ship but a war machine. It does rise up out the ground. Also stars Kate Winslet (I can't post any more links).

Comment: I think it wasn't part of a series (or the episodes weren't connected), because from what I remember the story ended with the movie.

Comment: Anyway I did see it a very long time ago.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out on Aquila! I was trying to find it for ages. I remember seeing it as a kid.