# Trying to find a film about a boy who finds a buried spaceship that then takes off with him

Tags: story-identification, movie

I‘m looking for a movie I watched at some point during (probably) the mid-1990s on German television (I don't know if it was dubbed or originally German). This is what I remember:

- the protagonist is a white boy around the age of maybe 10 who finds a (half-)buried spaceship around the beginning of the second half of the film (or maybe even later) in some kind of cool desert (or sea shore dunes), talks to it, and flies away in it
- the film starts in a town, and in my memory everything is desolate, not very populated
- the boy built model rockets, and they were put up on a table in the center of a desolate circular industrial building; I remember he had a NASA space shuttle with external tank and boosters, and maybe half a dozen others
- the boy was bullied by a group of others of around the same(?) age
- at some point they followed him into the building where his model rockets were, maybe laughing at him from a gallery on the first floor (?); I seem to remember the protagonist launches his rockets into the ceiling to drive them off, or maybe they just burn his models down... or a combination of both
- the protagonist visits an old man on some kind of deserted fairground in the dunes, and they talk; he might have taken seat on a broken carousel
- the boy wanders off into the dunes, and at some point finds the ship – it is at least partially buried, but parts of it can be seen; it is made of dark grey metal, if I remember correctly
- he climbs on top of it and falls into a hatch
- the interior of the ship was dark, and probably cramped; computers and monitors were on the walls – maybe I only remember the cockpit
- somehow the ship starts to talk to the boy
- the ship tells him it had been used by the humans for a long time, but that it was out of service now
- I remember the ship explaining how it provided food for its passengers; it had a machine that could fulfil every food order - more or less... which led the protagonist to order (amongst other things) square eggs or something like that (it was "eckige Eier" in the German version I watched); this was a big laugh for me as a child, with the food jumping out of the machine and making a small mess
- at the end of the movie, the ship powers up, and flies into space - with the protagonist on board; I don't remember what lead to this
- I‘m rather sure the launch wasn‘t shown from the outside – the scene just continued inside the cockpit
- the ship named its destination (I think it was some widely known star name) and calculated the travel time for the boy (could have been 80 years or something in that area)
- when the ship reaches orbit, I seem to remember there is some low-orbit view of earth - might be on a screen, or the protagonist looks through a window; anyway, I think that view is the background for the beginning end credits
- for all I know, it could even have been a short film, maybe less than 40 minutes long (but it could also be twice the length); the part in the end with the spaceship could have been around 20 minutes long
- there were not many characters, or complete parts of the film and characters might have completely vanished from my memory
- the film seemed rather slow-paced, and conveyed (at least to me) a feeling of desolateness

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to find a movie about a boy who finds a buried spaceship that then takes off](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102433/trying-to-find-a-movie-about-a-boy-who-finds-a-buried-spaceship-that-then-takes)

Comment: @Spencer This question is much more detailed than the proposed duplicate, so it should be closed in the other direction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the answer on a German speaking sci-fi forum: https://www.scifi-forum.de/forum/filme-tv-serien-und-co/tv-serien/36989-alte-scifi-serie-oder-film-gesucht

The film is a West German/Polish TV production from 1988. It‘s called „Flugfieber“ („Flying Fever“) in German, and „Stworzony do lotu“ („Meant for flying“) in Polish. It‘s 60 minutes long. In Germany, its first broadcast took place in 1988 on WDR channel, and it seems to have been repeated a couple of times in the 1990s. I didn‘t find out if it has been broadcasted anywhere outside Poland or Germany.

Here the imdb-site: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt12741734/

And – last but not least - the last 20 minutes of the film in German on Youtube:

It seems as if the only way to watch the whole film now is to request a copy from the respective television channel. The German version can be requested here:
https://wdr-mediagroup.com/geschaeftsfelder/i-o/mitschnittservice/

Comment: Here is the full 50+ minute film:
https://youtu.be/adv4RzqPJjM?si=x0x8XN2AE5BNi6Jw